# I am setting up a home web server and get a file not found micro-httpd error

Tags: apache, http, tcp, xampp

I am using xampp to setup a home web server with Wordpress to make a file server/website accessible from the internet.

I have gotten everything working locally. When using localhost or typing in my local IP there are no issues. When I attempt to access my Wordpress with my WAN IP, it throws this error:

404 Not Found
File not found.
micro_httpd

This occurs when I type in myipaddress:80/wp, which is the directory of my Wordpress. I didn't even get an error when I had .htaccess setup, so I deleted .htaccess and the password text file. Then, I got this error. Can someone offer any advice?? Thanks!!